# Bash Hex to Dec IP conversion in a file

Tags: bash, hex, ip-address

I have a file that has hundreds of lines that look similar to this:

```
index.=10200,intf.10200.4=eth1,vlan.10200.4=500,IP-Addr.10200.4=C0A80A78,uptime.10200.4=120days,duplex.10200.4=full,status.10200.4=up
index.=10201,intf.10201.25=eth1,vlan.10201.25=500,IP-Addr.10201.25=C0A80A79,uptime.10201.25=80days,duplex.10201.25=full,status.10201.25=up
index.=10202,intf.10202.6=eth1,vlan.10202.6=500,IP-Addr.10202.6=C0A80A80,uptime.10202.6=240days,duplex.10202.6=full,status.10202.6=up
```

I am trying to convert all the Hexadecimal IP address to Dotted Decimal by editing the file in place.
I have seen all the bash hex to dec ip converters online, but those are for entering a value then converting.

How would I go about editing values in place in a file?

More detailed data set:

```
index.=10200,CDP-Local-Intf.10200=FastEthernet0/0/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10200.44=C0A80A78,CDP-Uptime.10200.44=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10200.44=FastEthernet0/1/0,CDP-VLAN.10200.44=100,CDP-Duplex.10200.44=3,CDP-Other.10200.44=00000032
index.=10201,CDP-Local-Intf.10201=FastEthernet2/0/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10201.25=C0A80A79,CDP-Uptime.10201.25=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10201.25=FastEthernet0/2/0,CDP-VLAN.10201.25=101,CDP-Duplex.10201.25=3,CDP-Other.10201.25=00000032
index.=10202,CDP-Local-Intf.10202=FastEthernet2/1/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10202.11=C0A80A80,CDP-Uptime.10202.11=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10202.11=FastEthernet0/3/0,CDP-VLAN.10202.11=101,CDP-Duplex.10202.11=3,CDP-Other.10202.11=00000032
```

Comment: would [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025177/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-ip-address-to-dotted-decimal-notation) help?

Comment: I am not sure, that thread is a file where each line is an IP. 
Plus that post also has static strings before the Hex IP address, my file has random numbers between the index (10200.) and the =

Comment: this meant to be a "hint" how to do it and not as a complete solution. I believe this technique can be very simply adopted for your case. Good luck!

Comment: Doesnt that solution print the output to the screen? I am trying to replace each hex value in the file with its decimal format

Comment: That posts code does work, but it doesn't edit the file in place. I can find a conversion script anywhere, my issue is "editing the file in place"

Comment: If you have `gawk` then use the `inplace` flag

Comment: I do have a question about that thread you mentioned, so how is the awk command delimiting where the IP starts? When I delete the space after the colon for my test input file, the script breaks and puts out all 0.0.0.0 but I don't see any space delimiter in the awk command.

Comment: Also it appears the awk/gawk I have does not support the -i option as I do not see it in my man page. and when run it fails.
Looks like the gawk version I have does not support in place (no upgrade possible)

Comment: @ehammer, what does `gawk --version` return?

Comment: the version: GNU Awk 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `perl` is your option, would you try the following:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(CDP-IP-Addr[\d.]+=)([[:xdigit:]]{8})/$1 . join(".", unpack("C4", pack("H8", $2)))/e' datafile
```

- The `-i` option to `perl` enables the in-place editing.
- The `-pe` option tells perl to process the input file line by line as
  `sed` or `awk` does.
- The regex `(CDP-IP-Addr[\d.]+=)([[:xdigit:]]{8})` extracts the substring
  "CDP-IP-Addr.xx.xx=" and the following hexadecimal string. They are
  captured by `$1` and `$2` in order.
- The function `unpack("C4", pack("H8", $2))` converts the 8-digit hexadecimal
  string `$2` into an array of four decimal values.
- The `e` switch to the `s/regex/replacement/` operator tells perl to
  evaluate the replacement as a perl expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but if you don’t mind using Python to make this a quick conversion check out this link I found with a pretty simple Python script to knock that hex to decimal conversion.

http://pythonldap.blogspot.com/2014/09/python-script-to-convert-hexadecimal.html

If you need to convert a file of hex, try adding a for loop to iterate through the hex values and use that file as your argument.

Comment: The file formatting is done through a bash script, I just wanted to added another couple lines to convert all the Hex IP to dec IPs. As shown in my post, the file contains hex in specific fields, and I am not sure how to do find and replace in the file.

Comment: Wow, I should wear my glasses when reading ha ha!  Let me look into some BASH options for this.  My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

here's the `gawk` test harness - it use `gawk` specific functions and extensions.

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/.*=([[:xdigit:]]+),(CDP-Uptime|uptime).*/,a) {
  str = strtonum(sprintf("0x%s", a[1]))
  ip=sprintf ("%d.%d.%d.%d",
    rshift(and(str,0xff000000),24),
    rshift(and(str,0x00ff0000),16),
    rshift(and(str,0x0000ff00),08),
    rshift(and(str,0x000000ff),00))
  $0=substr($0,1,a[1,"start"]-1) ip substr($0,a[1,"start"]+a[1,"length"])
}
1

$ gawk -f tst.awk myFile myMoreDetailedFile
index.=10200,intf.10200.4=eth1,vlan.10200.4=500,IP-Addr.10200.4=192.168.10.120,uptime.10200.4=120days,duplex.10200.4=full,status.10200.4=up
index.=10201,intf.10201.25=eth1,vlan.10201.25=500,IP-Addr.10201.25=192.168.10.121,uptime.10201.25=80days,duplex.10201.25=full,status.10201.25=up
index.=10202,intf.10202.6=eth1,vlan.10202.6=500,IP-Addr.10202.6=192.168.10.128,uptime.10202.6=240days,duplex.10202.6=full,status.10202.6=up
index.=10200,CDP-Local-Intf.10200=FastEthernet0/0/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10200.44=192.168.10.120,CDP-Uptime.10200.44=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10200.44=FastEthernet0/1/0,CDP-VLAN.10200.44=100,CDP-Duplex.10200.44=3,CDP-Other.10200.44=00000032
index.=10201,CDP-Local-Intf.10201=FastEthernet2/0/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10201.25=192.168.10.121,CDP-Uptime.10201.25=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10201.25=FastEthernet0/2/0,CDP-VLAN.10201.25=101,CDP-Duplex.10201.25=3,CDP-Other.10201.25=00000032
index.=10202,CDP-Local-Intf.10202=FastEthernet2/1/1,CDP-IP-Addr.10202.11=192.168.10.128,CDP-Uptime.10202.11=Timeticks:(342342322)52days,CDP-Opposite-Intf.10202.11=FastEthernet0/3/0,CDP-VLAN.10202.11=101,CDP-Duplex.10202.11=3,CDP-Other.10202.11=00000032
```

This can definitely be stream-lined further.
Give it a whirl!

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong, but it runs without error but I dont see anything changed in the file.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the 1 at the end. It works, but is there a way to make it modify the file in place?

Comment: @ehammer, as of now it doesn't modify the original file - it simply outputs to stdout. Check the output first and later on when satisfied you can work on modifying the original file - that should be the least of your worries...

Comment: How would this command look if it were integrated into a bash script? would it just be awk match () {}?

Comment: I don't quite remember when the `inplace` gawk extension was introduced, but you can either try:
1: `gawk -i inplace -f tst.awk myFile`
or if `inplace` isn't supported/installed:
2. `gawk -f tst.awk myFile > /tmp/myFile && mv /tmp/myFile myFile`

Comment: @ehammer, as far as the `How would this command look if it were integrated into a bash script`, I'll leave it up to you find the answer to that. This could simply be Googled/searched and should be the least of your worries.

Comment: Yeah, I can make that work. The problem I have now is that it appears my real data set is a little more complex than the example provided and that script isnt converting the IP, I'm testing each field and finding out which one is causing the issue. At a glance it looks like the string: ```=333,``` is getting converted to 0.0.0.3

Comment: I'm going to add a more complex data set to my original post, because I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: @ehammer, this is turning into a Chameleon question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) which are highly discouraged.
I'll update the suggested solution on your latest data sample, but it should be considered the **exception** to the rule - you should REALLY provide a **representative** data sample and the expected results. And not iterate over all possible cases you might encounter. 
Don't be "confused" - just provide a representative data sample going forward.

Comment: Due to the dynamic nature of some data sets, I would say discovering an unknown is perfectly within the norm. I try to include everything that could possibly pop up with my data, but I can't predict every piece. I apologize if this is excessive.

Comment: @ehammer does the latest update fulfills your requirement? If it does not, provide ONE data sample  with as many representative data cases as you can identify.

Comment: Unfortunately new things are inevitable. Could you explain what each part of that awk file does so I can better understand how its matching and converting?